# \colorlet{saved}{.} inside caption produces error

Tags: color, captions

`\colorlet{saved}{.}` inside `caption` produces an error. I don't understand why? How can I fix this? Are there better alternatives to `\colorlet{saved}{.}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Example of a parametric plot ($\colorlet{saved}{.}\sin (x), \cos(x), x$)}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

realistic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{X}
{
  name={\ensuremath{X}},
  description={Some quantity that changes over time can have index (corresponding to the time) and superscript}
}

\newcommand{\Xsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{X}{X\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{t}
{
  name={\ensuremath{t}},
  description={time can have index and superscript}
}

\newcommand{\tsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{t}{t\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}{}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{\color{blue} Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (\Xsubsuper{3}{5}), \cos(x), x$)}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}


\noindent$X_1^3$\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{}_1^3$ wrong spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{1}{3}$ correct spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{3}$\\
{\color{green}
$\tsubsuper{1}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\Xsubsuper{\tsubsuper{1}{3}}{3}$}

\printglossary[title=Notation,toctitle=Notation]

\end{document}
```

It produces the correct pdf as far as I can see, but it gives 2 error messages:

**Argument of \Hy@tempa has an extra }.**

```
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.33 ...t ($\sin (\Xsubsuper{3}{5}), \cos(x), x$)}
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

and

**Runaway argument?**

```
\@captype {\XC@colorlet }\def \reserved@b {\XC@colorlet [{}]}\futurelet \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Hy@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.33 ...t ($\sin (\Xsubsuper{3}{5}), \cos(x), x$)}
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: why on earth do you want to save the color there?

Comment: Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I consider an insult to the reader having a link to the glossary for every appearance of some notation.

Comment: as before you could use `\protect` but you should not be making definitions in a caption.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I only want X to have the linkcolor, but not its index nor its power

Comment: or replace `newcommand` by `\DeclareRobustCommand`

Comment: Every caption will be written to the aux file for which it will be expanded. Use `\protect` in front of `\colorlet` or make your `\Xsubsuper` robust but that will save the color once in the table of figures and once with the original `\caption`. You probably want to save the color only once where the `caption` is placed. Either do it before the `\caption` or in a way that it is not written to the table of figures. (Some classes allow `\caption[entry for table of figures]{entry for caption}`.) — What are you even trying to do? Maybe there's a much better approach.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\protect` inside the \newcommand does not help. Directly in front oft \Xsupsuper it works well :) I don't want to define X in the caption, but I want every occurrence of X to be linked to the notation glossary. It's nice for reading a paper with heavy notation (especially since some pdf viewers support a little preview of hyperlinks at mouse-over :)

Comment: `\protect` was from the first version using `\colorlet` directly, see answer to make your defined command robust. But why do this at all why not simply make the base of your construct the link so the subscripts naturally do not pick up the link colour?

Comment: sorry but like @egreg I think you are overdoing. I simply loath documents where you jump around as soon as you touch something because everything has been turned into a link. Beside this, be aware that ifthenelse isn't the fastest command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would prefer to do so, but unfortunately hyperlinks get boxed, so that `\X_{sub}^{super}` would result in wrong spacing as shown in the example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer [you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You) [don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t) [like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like) [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link) [?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark)

Comment: @Jakob maybe you should instead ask about that. Possibly something like the `\mathcolor` addition to `\textcolor` which avoids that problem for color could be thought of.

Comment: @Jakob `$\rlap{\glslink{X}{\phantom{X}}}\mathcolor{linkcolor}{X}_1^3$` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This sounds interesting. egreg thought yesterday, that such as solution would probably not really be possible: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64681769#64681769

Comment: never trust @egreg :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle with lualatex it should be possible to use attributes to create the links, that wouldn't affect the spacing at all, see e.g. https://github.com/zauguin/lua-links

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `$\mathrlap{\glslink{X}{\phantom{X}}}\mathcolor{linkcolor}{X}_1^3$` is even better with `\mathrlap` from the package `mathtools` compared to `\rlap`. Because it can also be used inside supscripts and superscripts: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701482/rlap-in-subscript-leads-to-larger-subscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need such constructs you should hide them in a robust command, eg as defined by `\NewDocumentCommand`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}


\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{X}
{
  name={\ensuremath{X}},
  description={Some quantity that changes over time can have index (corresponding to the time) and superscript}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\Xsubsuper{mm}{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{X}{X\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\newglossaryentry{t}
{
  name={\ensuremath{t}},
  description={time can have index and superscript}
}

\newcommand{\tsubsuper}[2]{\colorlet{saved}{.}\ensuremath{\glslink{t}{t\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{_{\mathcolor{saved}{#1}}}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}{}}{}{^{\mathcolor{saved}{#2}}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{\color{blue} Example of a parametric plot ($\sin (\Xsubsuper{3}{5}), \cos(x), x$)}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}


\noindent$X_1^3$\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{}_1^3$ wrong spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{1}{3}$ correct spacing\\
$\Xsubsuper{}{3}$\\
{\color{green}
$\tsubsuper{1}{3}$\\
$\tsubsuper{}{3}$\\
$\Xsubsuper{\tsubsuper{1}{3}}{3}$}

\printglossary[title=Notation,toctitle=Notation]

\end{document}
```