# \rlap in subscript leads to larger subscript

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts, superscripts, overlap

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
$M_{\theta}$ % correct size theta
$M_{\rlap{\ensuremath{\theta}}}$ % too large theta
\end{document}
```

[image]
Why does this happen? How can I fix it? In my case the `\rlap` is inisede a command that I would like to work inside and outside of supscripts and superscripts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\rlaptheta}{\rlap{\ensuremath{\theta}}} % I would like the command to work both in normal mode as well as in subscript or superscruit

\begin{document}
$M_{\theta}$ % correct size theta
$M_{\rlap{\ensuremath{\theta}}}$ % too large theta

$M_{\rlaptheta}$ % too large theta

$\theta\rlaptheta$ %correct size

%The same for superscripts
$M^{\theta}$ % correct size theta
$M^{\rlaptheta}$ % too large theta
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Always been like that. `\rlap` is thought to be for text and does not scale in subscripts. Use `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package.

Comment: The definition of `\rlap` is `\def\rlap#1{\hbox to 0pt{#1\hss}}`. Note that the `<stuff>` in `M_{\hbox{$<stuff>$}}` won't get subscript size unless you specify `\scriptstyle` explicitly.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this answers my question.