# Hyperlink in math mode with correct spacing for flexible use with subscripts and superscripts

Tags: math-mode, spacing, hyperref, kerning

I want to use hyperlinks in math mode without changing the spacing or kerning. I.e., I want to define a command `\mathhyperref` similar to [Correct kerning of hyperlinks in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141779/correct-kerning-of-hyperlinks-in-math-mode) but more flexible (I don't want to use different commands depending on if there is a subscript or not and so on). I managed to deal with subscripts (based on [\colorlet{saved}{.} inside caption produces error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700741/colorletsaved-inside-caption-produces-error?noredirect=1#comment1742237_700741) by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)), but I am still struggeling with `\tilde{}`:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor,mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}
\newcommand{\mathlinkcolor}[1]{\mathcolor{linkcolor}{#1}}

\newcommand{\mathhyperref}[2]{\mathrlap{\hyperref[#1]{\phantom{\ensuremath{#2}}}}\mathlinkcolor{#2}}

\newcommand{\linkedtheta}{\mathhyperref{def:theta}{\theta}}
%\newcommand{\linkedtheta}{\mathrlap{\hyperref[def:theta]{\phantom{\ensuremath{\theta}}}}\mathlinkcolor{\theta}} % I would like the command to work as similar to theata in terms of spacing as possible, but it should be linked and colored

\begin{document}
$\tilde{\theta}$ %correct

$\tilde{\linkedtheta}$ %wrong (the tilde is too far left)


$M_{\theta}$ % correct 

$M_{\linkedtheta}$ % correct I think


$\linkedtheta_a^b$ % correct I think

$\theta_a^b$ % correct


\begin{definition}\label{def:theta}
    $\linkedtheta$
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `\skew{3}\tilde{\linkedtheta}`? It might be possible to patch `\tilde` but I don't think it would be worth it...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't like it at all if everything is made a link. It make navigating a pdf difficult if you jump around as soon as you touch something. But if you really want you could try lualatex and the (highly experimental) lua-links package from https://github.com/zauguin/lua-links

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage[discard,tightH,tightV,unbox]{lua-links}
\usepackage{amsthm,xcolor,mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\colorlet{linkcolor}{red!70}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=linkcolor}

\newcommand{\mathhyperref}[2]{\hyperref[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\linkedtheta}{\mathhyperref{def:theta}{\theta}}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{\theta}$ %correct

$\tilde{\linkedtheta}$ %wrong (the tilde is too far left)


$M_{\theta}$ % correct 

$M_{\linkedtheta}$ % correct I think


$\linkedtheta_a^b$ % correct I think

$\theta_a^b$ % correct


\begin{definition}\label{def:theta}
    $\linkedtheta$
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]